# How to export powerpoint (pptx) to video with animations programmatically using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to export powerpoint presentation to video programmatically. I have tried following.

1. Open pptx file using `org.apache.poixslf.usermodel.SlideShow`
2. Update the slides as per requirement
3. Create image for each slide (using `slide.draw()`)
4. Create a video by appending slide images one after the other

The code is generating a video. The video is collection of static images of slides. The problem is the animations contained in a slide is not present in the video.

Is there any way to get the animations exported in the video using apache.poi or any other option ?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html highlights the PPTX2PNG sample

Comment: @PJFanning I have already tried PPTX2PNG. It converts slide to png but not with animations. It gives a static image of the slide. I want the animations. So, if the image could be provided after each animation frame, that will work for me. But that is not possible with PPTX2PNG.